# How can I get Vite to work through a proxy on a different domain?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, cors, vite

I have a `React` app that I build using `Vite` and is hosted on my own domain, which I allow to be displayed in an `iframe` for use on other people's websites. Something along the lines of:

```
<iframe src="https://www.example.com/app/"></iframe>
```

However, some of the other websites need to load my app via a proxy `php` script that they've written, something like (but not nearly as simplified as):

```
<?php
    // proxy.php
    echo file_get_contents( "https://www.example.com/app/");
?>

<iframe src="https://www.theirSite.com/proxy.php"></iframe>
```

The problem though, is that the index.html file that `Vite` creates wants to use javascript modules, and those immediately get a cross-origin CORS error when we attempt to load them this way, even though they have a `crossorigin` attribute like so:

```
<script type="module" crossorigin src="https://www.example.com/app/assets/index-asdf.js"></script>
```

Adding CORS headers doesn't work, see below for details.

Can I get `Vite` to stop using modules entirely? Note that `@vitejs/plugin-legacy` doesn't work, see below for details.

## Additional Info

### Why are they using this proxy in the first place?

The reason they do this is not very relevant to the problem - but to satisfy your curiosity, it's often because they're using screen recorders that would not record the activity inside the `iframe` if it were loaded remotely like in the first scenario. If they use the proxy, the content is loaded from their own domain (the proxy), and therefore the user activity is recorded.

### Why not just add `Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"` to the .js files?

I've tried everything to get `Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"` added to the .js files the app needs to load, but it doesn't work. I've come to the conclusion that it's perhaps a security thing. Again not relevant to the question I'm asking, but here is the latest `.htaccess` file I've used for testing on my domain:

```
<FilesMatch "\.(js|xjson)$">
    #Order deny,allow
    #Deny from all
    <ifModule mod_headers.c>
        Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
        Header set Access-Control-Allow-Headers "origin, x-requested-with, content-type"
        Header set Access-Control-Allow-Methods: "GET,OPTIONS"
    </ifModule>
</FilesMatch>
```

When I check the headers of a dummy .xjson file, it correctly has everything above. But when I check any of the .js files, the headers are not there (an no it's not a cache issue, I've used Chrome's `empty cache and hard reload` and I've also used external header checkers - the CORS headers *are not there*). If I uncomment the `Deny from all` command, the .js files become unreachable with a 403 error. So the point is, **I know for sure** that my server *can* add the headers if it wants to, and **I know for sure** that it *does* see the .js files I'm telling it to look for - but the headers do not show up. So my tentative conclusion after hours of failures is that maybe there's a security hole that opens up if you add CORS headers to a .js file, so the server is refusing to do it.

So, if I can't get that CORS header to show up, then I have to get `Vite` to stop using imports.

### OK fine, then why doesn't `@vitejs/plugin-legacy` work?

Let's just use `@vitejs/plugin-legacy` right? Wrong, because the resulting `index.html` file from that build still wants to use modules if they're supported. It has a bunch of gobbledy-gook that checks to see if the user's browser supports modules, and if so, it tries to use them, and only falls back if needed. But in my case, *it doesn't matter* if the browser supports modules or not, I can't use them because of the CORS error mentioned above.

### Why are you even using `Vite` in the first place?

It might sound like I'm trying to get `Vite` to behave a lot like `create-react-app` - I am! But I switched to `Vite` specifically because `create-react-app` is no longer supported, and it *seemed* like `Vite` was the *new hotness* that would replace *old busted*. Should I just switch back and use *old busted*?

**So, can I get `Vite` to just stop using modules in the final build? No attempting, no checking, no being smart - just get rid of them entirely?**